# $filter('date') returns same date regardless on timezone

Tags: angularjs, date

```
ctrl.time1 =  $filter('date')(new Date(),"MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
ctrl.time2 =  $filter('date')(new Date(),"MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss", "-06:00");
```

On the page:

```
<div>ctrl.time1: {{::dateTimeCtrl.time1}}</div>
<div>ctrl.time2: {{::dateTimeCtrl.time2}}</div>
```

time1 = time2 = Feb 05 2015 - 09:16:25

I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe this?

From [AngularJS date filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

> `$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)`
>
> ...
>
> `timezone` (optional): Timezone to be used for formatting. Right now, only 'UTC' is
>   supported. If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

What about trying the following:

```
$scope.time1 =  $filter('date')(new Date(),"MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
$scope.time2 =  $filter('date')(new Date(),"MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss -0600");
```